Issue with Error Type Logs in OpenIddict v5.2.0
I am currently experiencing an issue with logging error types while using OpenIddict.
In version 4.8.0, error type logs were correctly captured. However, after upgrading
to the latest version (5.2.0), these logs are being generated under the
information log type. After the upgrade, OpenIddict error type logs are not generated.
Both version logs are the same, but I expect the log type to be 'error' in this log.
However, after the OpenIddict upgrade, that log is captured under the log type 'info'.
[4.8.0 Log]
[ERR] (OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerDispatcher) The authorization request was rejected because the redirect_uri was invalid: '"http://localhost:81/signin-callback"'.
[5.2.0 Log]
[INF] (OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerDispatcher) The authorization request was rejected because the redirect_uri was invalid: '"http://localhost:81/signin-callback"'.
Could you please clarify if there have been any changes related to logging in the latest
version that might be causing this behavior? For context, I am using Serilog for log capturing.
Below is the relevant section of my project's appsettings.json file where the logger is configured based on
Serilog:
"Logger": {
"BasePath": "RootPath",
"MinimumLevel": {
"Default": "Error",
"Override": {
"ComponentSpace": "Error",
"OpenIddict": "Error"
}
}
}
